# null value generates while converting the date from one format to another format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am having a date format "16-11-2011". but I want to convert it into  "16 Nov"
I written the code for it but null value generates instead of the format "16 Nov"

for this I have written following code

```
NSDate *checkIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"CHECK_1"];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@",checkIn);

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
    NSString *checkInDate = [formatter stringFromDate:checkIn];
    NSLog(@"checkInDate:%@",checkInDate);
```

and the results display by nslog statements are as follows:

```
Date: 16-11-2011
checkInDate:(null)
```

so I am not able to convert it into the format which I want

plz help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `checkIn` is a `NSString` not `NSDate`.
Therefore, you would have to convert it to a `NSDate` first and then convert it back to the desired string format.

```
NSString *checkIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"CHECK_1"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *checkInTempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:checkIn];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *checkInDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:checkInTempDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first line:

```
NSDate *checkIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"CHECK_1"];
```

`NSUserDefaults` does not have a method `valueForKey`, it is Key Value Coding" that is returning a value. `NSUserDefaults` also does not handle dates.  What you are getting back from `NSUserDefaults` is a string, by a quirk `NSDate` is accepting that.

The last 4 lines of code are correct but need a date, checkIn is a string.

To test this put this line of code after the first line, ignore any incompatible type warning):

```
NSLog(@"class name: %s", class_getName([checkIn class]));
```